# Laravel 5.3 Scope Return

Tags: laravel, scope

I'm having problem with this scope in my product Model

My scope look like this:

```
public function scopeLessNinetyDays( $query ){

    $date = new \Carbon\Carbon;
    $date->subWeek(12); 

    return $query->where('created_at', '<', $date->toDateTimeString())->get() ;
}
```

I tried to loop it in category and the result is at the bottom. I need to return true or false. If the product created_at is in 12 weeks already. This is weird because it returns collection. Instead of single product.

```
 @foreach( $category->product->take(4) as $product )
       {{ dd($product->lessNinetyDays()) }}
    @endforeach
```

[image]

If I used this code it returns single product. See Image at the bottom.

```
@foreach( $category->product->take(4) as $product )
   {{ dd($product) }}
@endforeach
```

[image]

I don't know how to achieved that goal because of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly using a **Local Scope**. Scopes are used when selecting rows from the database, only that match the defined scope.

What you are looking for, is something like a "fake attribute" (**accessor**), which is probably the most Eloquent way of achieving what you are wishing for.

First, define this accessor:

```
public function getIsLessNinetyDaysAttribute() {
  $date = (new \Carbon\Carbon)->subWeek(12);

  return $this->created_at->lt($date);
}
```

Now, you can access this property by using:

```
@foreach( $category->product->take(4) as $product )
   {{ dd($product->is_less_ninety_days) }}
@endforeach
```

This should return either *true* or *false*.

---

**Example for using a local Scope**

After defining this scope:

```
public function scopeLessNinetyDays( $query ){

  $date = new \Carbon\Carbon;
  $date->subWeek(12); 

  return $query->where('created_at', '<', $date->toDateTimeString())->get();
}
```

Now, you can chain this scope to your **select** query:

```
@foreach( $category->product->lessNinetyDays()->get() as $product )
   {{ dd($product) }}
@endforeach
```

In this foreach loop, the only rows returned are the rows that are matching the lessNinetyDays scope.

There a multiple ways to achieve your goal, but in such cases, I always prefer an accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Scope's are for query selecting. See [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes)

If you just add the following to the model then it should return true or false.

```
public function lessNinetyDays()
{
    $date = new \Carbon\Carbon;
    $date->subWeek(12);

    return $this->created_at > $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the scope incorrectly.

It's not supposed to return anything - it's only supposed to modify the query, it shouldn't return anything, especially the results of the query. Therefore you should replace

```
return $query->where('created_at', '<', $date->toDateTimeString())->get() ;
```

with

```
$query->where('created_at', '<', $date->toDateTimeString());
```

Then, if you want to fetch products that were created within last 90 days, you'll need to do the following:

```
$products->lessNinetyDays()->get();
```

See more info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes